# HoW to check VIF SCORE

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z913Q.png)

I wANTt to read each column one by one and check its vif score with others BUT THIS ERROR POPS UP

Comment: Print out what data.columns.shape is

Answer (score 0):

`IndexError` simple says that the index is out of range. its not in the array. let me give an example

```py
array = [1, 2, 3]  # Create a Array with 3 Elements
# Outputs the IndexError since the 4th element doesn't exist
element = array[3] # (Keep In Mind We Also Start Counting on 0)
```

another example can be for a dict

```py
dict = {"spam": "egg", "foo": "bar"} # Create a Dictionary with 3 keys & values
value = dict["mykey"] # Outputs Error Since there is no key named "mykey" in dict
```

a valid case could be

```py
array = [1, 2, 3] # Creates a Array with 3 Elements
element = array[2] # Doesn't Output Error, Index 2 Exists with Element "3"
```

So in conclusion you are searching for something that simply doesn't exist. I cannot help further as i don't have a lot of information about what the code looks like, what you are trying to achieve. I also don't know how the csv file(the dataframe) looks at the first place